# Which one is the correct tag: 'doesn't', 'isn't, or 'hasn't'?

Tags: sentence-construction, tag-questions

> Ravi has been demanding a lot more marks, **doesn't he**?

Is this usage correct? Or do we have replace **doesn't he** with **hasn't he** or **isn't it**?

Kindly explain the difference between the three with suitable examples.

Comment: "hasn't he" is more suitable here, as it is a perfect tense. Isn't it use for things I quess, and doesn't use with present tenses.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about **question tags**.

[Question tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) are the small parts that are turned into a question at the ends of sentences. Your example sentence, *"Ravi has been demanding a lot more marks"*, can be turned into a question by adding the tag ***hasn't he?***

We normally use question tags in speech. "To check information or ask for agreement, we most often put negative tags after affirmation sentences, and non-negative tags after negative sentences." (*Practical English Usage*, by Michael Swan, (PEU) 487.2 negative after affirmative, and vice versa). – That's why you need a negative tag in your example. It's because ***Ravi has been demanding ...*** is an affirmative sentence.

"If the main sentence has an auxiliary verb (or non-auxiliary *be*), this is repeated in the question tag." (PEU 487.3 auxiliaries)

In your example,

> ***Ravi*** - a noun (the subject)
>   ***has*** - an auxiliary verb
>   ***been*** - an auxiliary verb
>   ***demanding*** - a main verb (also known as "lexical verb")
>   ***a lot more marks*** - a noun group (the object)

When we have more than one auxiliary verbs, we usually use only the first one in the question tag. Your sentence has two, *has* and *been*; ***has*** is the first auxiliary verb; so your sentence, with a question tag, would become:

> *Ravi **has been demanding** a lot more marks, **hasn't he**?*

---

The **auxiliary verb** of the main clause tells us which of ***doesn't he***, ***hasn't he*** and ***isn't it*** we should use in the tag. We use the same auxiliary verb in both the main clause and in the tag. This also applies when you can't see the auxiliary verb (we use the auxiliary verb ***do***; this is also known as [Do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)). Here are some examples straight from the Wikipedia page:

> *He **has** read this book, **hasn't he?***
>   *He'**s reading** this book, **isn't he?***
>   *He **reads** a lot of books, **doesn't he?*** -- (note that we use the auxiliary **do**, i.e. ***doesn't*** in the tag)

---

#### EXAM TIPS

**Always know your verbs**.
Know which one is the **main verb** of a clause, and which is an **auxiliary** (if there is one or more).

1. In your English exams, some questions will try to have you confuse ***isn't*** with ***hasn't***. The most common trick is by using a contraction. For example, your example could have been written:

> *Ravi'**s been** demanding a lot more marks.*

- Because '***s*** can be used for ***is*** and ***has***, you have to be able to recognize when '***s*** is used for ***is*** and when it's used for ***has***. Or else, you won't be able to pick the right auxiliary verb in the tag.

---

2. It's widely noted in grammar books for learners (and also in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)) that for ***He has a book***, either tag ***hasn't he?*** and ***doesn't he?*** are acceptable. (*Doesn't he* is normal in American English.) Some tests turn this against you, and ask for the question tag of ***has been***:

> *Ravi **has been** demanding a lot more marks.*

- Because you know that in *He has a book* both are possible, you may be confused which to use between *hasn't he?* and *doesn't he?* in your example. So, what is the solution?
- This will go back to the tip "Always know your verbs". In American English, the verb ***has*** in *He has a book* is a main verb (a lexical verb). It has its own meaning: it's used for showing possession. But in your example, *"Ravi has been demanding a lot more marks"*, ***has*** is only an auxiliary verb. So, you use ***hasn't he?*** (not <del>*doesn't he?*</del>).